# What is the purpose of calling setTimeout with a delay of 1?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

In the [quickstart guide for the Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js#step_2_set_up_the_sample), the following function is called once the client library has loaded:

```
// Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
function handleClientLoad() {
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
}
```

What is the purpose of calling `setTimeout` with a delay of 1 like this instead of just calling `checkAuth` immediately?

Comment: *related*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360238/myfunction-vs-window-settimeoutmyfunction-0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Javascript has asynchronous I/O (ajax/requests) as well as `setTimeout` and `setInterval`,

One use of running `setTimeout` with 1 milisecond (or 0) would be to tell that code to be run *after* the synchronous code following it. Here is an example

```
setTimeout(function(){
     alert("World");
},1); 
alert("Hello");

//alerts "Hello" then "World"
```

I wanted to keep my answer simple and to the point, if you're interested, there is more details about how setTimeout works in [the MDN article about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: I was going to provide a link, and this proved fatal for my rep :P

Answer (score 7):

By using `setTimeout` you allow the page to be interactive before the `checkAuth` function completes.

Essentially, you are preventing the `checkAuth` from holding up the page.

As a side note, the minimum delay specified in the HTML5 specification is 5ms, so a wait of 1ms will actually be a wait of 5ms. If it is important for you to reclaim that time, you can achieve the same result with a 0ms delay by using `window.postMessage`. This was originally designed to handle cross-origin communication, but has [a similar effect as setting a timeout with 0ms](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts) (which you can't do as browsers only allow 5ms - or 10ms in some older browsers).

Lastly, the timing is not guaranteed. JavaScript runs on a single thread, so when you push something out onto a timer it must wait for an opening in the execution of the rest of the JavaScript before it gets to take its turn on the thread - it doesn't run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout(function, 1)` will make `function` run after the current thread of execution is complete. JavaScript in a browser window runs in a single thread. So, even if the timeout is 1, it won't run until after the current execution is over. for example consider the following script:

```
window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);

// long code that takes 5 seconds to complete


function checkAuth() {
    alert("i m here!");
}
```

In the above example, you will see the alert after 5 seconds.

Comment: In javascript (with the exception of node.js child processes/threads_a_gogo, and web workers) there is only one thread of execution.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well I was sure that it runs in a single thread at least in the browser, and that's what the OP is concerned about. But thanks for the info.